# Deadlock when using Spring transaction

Tags: spring

I have the following classes and methods as below:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Transactional("emp")
public class EmployeeService {

}

@Component
public class HumanResourceManager {

[...]

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Transactional("emp")
public void checkEmployee(Employee emp) {

[..]

employeeService.saveEmployee(emp);

[...]

}

My Spring config:

<bean id="employeeDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${employee.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${employee.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${employee.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${employee.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="employeeDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xyz.employee.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${employee.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show.sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="employeeSessionFactory" />
        <qualifier value="emp" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="employeeTransactionManager" />
```

I got exception `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`! and in exception stacktrace this error happened at method `checkEmployee`.
Why is this error happenning when the default Propagation of Transaction is REQUIRED? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the data you provide is not enough. Try to remove the `@Transactional("emp")` from the class `EmployeeService` and place it at a method level. That would relieve the db to start unneeded transactions.

Try enabling `debug` log level for `org.springframework.orm` and see what is happenning.

Add to your question the whole chain, also add every call to `Autowired` services inside the `checkEmployee`.

Bear in mind that `@Transactional` only applies  after passing thru a `proxy` and the method must be visible (no `private` methods). Your `private method checkEmployee` is not applying its `@Transactional` annotation, it is indeed inheriting from its caller. As long as its caller is `public` annotated with @Transactional and called from a proxy (eg autowired).

Another thing that can help is to set a breakpoint in the call to `saveOrUpdate` in `saveEmployee` and check how many transactions are in `db`. In mysql `SHOW INNODB STATUS\G`

The commit is issued when the top level method (the which started the most inner transaction) returns trhu a proxy. This applies for every transaction you start.

Comment: It not worked. The propagation of transaction is REQUIRED means there is only 1 transaction for that thread, but deadlock occured means that there are more than 1 transaction created and they try to lock and commit DB

Comment: Are any other call to autowired methods in the last method?

Comment: Yes, it still call saveOrUpdate method of EmployeeService

Comment: Once you exit the top level method that passed tru a proxy, when returning will apply the commit.

Comment: When we call checkEmployee(), Propagation.REQUIRED will create a new transaction (if none exists for the current thread), or will join an existing transaction (if one exists). It means that only one thread has only one tranasction at that time. When it exits that checkEmployee() method db transaction will be applied the commit?

Comment: will apply the commit only if you did not commited or flushed. And also if its caller is not annotated. checkEmployee commit if it opened the transaction.

Comment: In this case, checkEmployee() annotated with @Transactional then it call EmployeeService bean, so EmployeeService will use the same transaction of checkEmployee() ? Because both of them are REQUIRED

Comment: unless it is annotated otherwise (REQUIRES_NEW). If it is REQUIRED it will. Stop the execution and query DB for open transactions

Comment: I fixed it, remove the @Transactional of checkEmployee() method. It will force Spring to commmit transaction after each method call in EmployeeService instead of completing "big" transaction